# Android Studio Bluetooth LE gatt sample scan finds RN4871 on samsung galaxy 3 & alcatel fierce XL, but cannot on both of my HTC 's

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have compiled and signed the sample and it scans and connects flawlessly to the Microchip RN4871 on the Samsung Galaxy 3 & Alcatel Fierce XL. However, the scan does not find the RN4871 on either of my HTC's.

The HTC's can see the RN4871 in the settings -> Bluetooth menu, and will pair.
Even after this, the app still fails to find the device when it scans.

I plan on trying to get the mac address from the list of paired devices and trying to connect that way.

What kind of device specific issue could I be running into?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: wow that was fast, but I had to turn on location services under setting->apps->"app name" then turn on location services